# AWS Lambda Serverless Application - .Net Core vs Asp.Net Core (multiple vs single)

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I came across these 2 articles about creating multiples Lambda functions - [Asp.net core serverless app](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnet-core-aws-lambda-serverless-application/) and [.Net core serverless app](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/dotnet-core-aws-lambda-serverless-application/). From my understanding, to create AWS Lambda Serverless Application using Visual Studio, I've 2 options:

**Option 1: Asp.net core method (ASP.NET Core Web API in VS)**

- Only 1 Lambda function is created. The Asp.net core hosting will
  handle the routing to the respective method being called

**Option 2: .Net core method (Empty Serverless Application in VS)**

- Multiple Lambda functions are created.

A few things in my mind:

1. In [Option 1], since only 1 Lambda function, **performance** might be poorer (?) since it has to depend on the Asp.net core hosting to route to the respective method.
2. In [Option 1], it is more **costly** (?) because I will need more memory allocation
3. Better **versioning** of the methods/Lambda functions using [Option 2] because each methods correspond to a Lambda function (resource).
4. Better **maintainability** with [Option 2]

How are you guys doing it? Which options are better? Any other consideration that I should be aware of?